# SSL Connection fails after CLIENT HELLO

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm having some issues connecting to a 3rd party website over https, where the connection fails on the CLIENT HELLO and I'm stumped as to why this is happening.

Ironically, switching the laptop to the backup internet connection, I'm able to connect to the website fine, but it fails on the primary internet connection. This leads me to believe its not the laptop. (unfortunately, permanently switching to the backup connection is not a viable solution).

Using tcpdump I can see the packets going back and forth, and the client re-transmitting the hello a few times, but never getting past that. Using OpenSSL to troubleshoot, I get the output below. I've tried adding -ssl3 and -tls1 to no avail. Does anyone know WHY this happens and HOW I can fix it?

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x600070920 [0x600070d20] (316 bytes => 316 (0x13C))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 37 01 00 01-33 03 03 07 2f eb a9 10   ....7...3.../...
0010 - e7 e3 03 29 62 46 5b 03-6b cf 3f ab 0a 83 6b fe   ...)bF[.k.?...k.
0020 - b1 a6 fa 4c 5f 1a eb 9e-d4 5e 14 00 00 b4 c0 30   ...L_....^.....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   .<./...A........
00c0 - 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d   ................
00d0 - c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15-00 12 00 0f 00 0c 00 09   ................
00e0 - 00 ff 02 01 00 00 55 00-0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00   ......U.........
00f0 - 0a 00 1c 00 1a 00 17 00-19 00 1c 00 1b 00 18 00   ................
0100 - 1a 00 16 00 0e 00 0d 00-0b 00 0c 00 09 00 0a 00   ................
0110 - 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20 00-1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05   #..... .........
0120 - 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04-02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03   ................
0130 - 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00-0f 00 01 01               ............
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 37
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0137], ClientHello
    01 00 01 33 03 03 07 2f eb a9 10 e7 e3 03 29 62
    46 5b 03 6b cf 3f ab 0a 83 6b fe b1 a6 fa 4c 5f
    1a eb 9e d4 5e 14 00 00 b4 c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1 00 9f 00 6b 00
    6a 00 69 00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37 00 36 00 88 00
    87 00 86 00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0
    05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0 00 9e 00 67 00
    40 00 3f 00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 30 00 9a 00
    99 00 98 00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43 00 42 c0 31 c0
    2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00
    96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0
    12 c0 08 00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d c0 0d c0 03 00
    0a 00 15 00 12 00 0f 00 0c 00 09 00 ff 02 01 00
    00 55 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c 00 1a
    00 17 00 19 00 1c 00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16 00 0e
    00 0d 00 0b 00 0c 00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00 00 0d
    00 20 00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03
    04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02
    02 03 00 0f 00 01 01
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0x600070920 [0x600076280] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
2283136:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 316 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
```

Comment: Have you run the site through ssllabs.com server test to check out the SSL setup? Would also answer Steffen's suggestion on IPv6 being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `SSLProtocol All +SSLv2 +SSLv3` or `SSLProtocol All`

Comment: Tried this, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 316 bytes

This says that the connection gets closed immediately by the server or some middlebox (firewall or similar) in between.

I don't know what the difference between your internet connections is but I suspect any of these:

- With one connection you have IPv6 but not with the other. And while the server has an IPv6 address it is not properly setup on this address. In this case the connection will work fine on the IPv4 only network but not on the IPv6 network. See https://serverfault.com/a/676200/208324 for a similar problem.
- One internet connection has a firewall or other middlebox in between which blocks the connection.